# widthIn modifier inside a container using height(IntrinsicSize.Max) causes content to be clipped

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have the following requirements for this Composable function:

1. It needs to grow based on the size of its content, so no fixed height can be used.
2. It has an item (green) that grows as big as the content.
3. One or more of the items of variable height, have a fixed width.

This is the code I came up with:

```
@Composable
private fun Problem() {
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(IntrinsicSize.Max)
    ) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .background(Color.Green)
        ) {
            Spacer(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .width(40.dp)
                    .fillMaxHeight()
            )
        }
        Column(
            Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .background(Color.White)
        ) {
            Text(
                modifier = Modifier.background(Color.Red),
                color = Color.White,
                text = "XAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAX"
            )
            Text(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .background(Color.Blue)
                    .width(150.dp),
                color = Color.White,
                text = "XBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBX"
            )
        }
    }
}
```

This works almost perfectly, except it seems when a fixed width or a `widthIn` constraint is set on one of the items in this `height(IntrinsicSize.Max)` container, the last item cannot calculate its intrinsic height correctly.

[image: Image of the bug, the bottom text is clipped]

Why is this the case? could it be a bug in Compose?